# Is this combination feasible for image stitching using Python 3.8 and openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching, brisk

I was assigned for an image stitching project. As a beginner, I had read and learnt a lot from the Internet. Below are my combination of techniques used by me to implement image stitching. Are they feasible?  I use python 3.8 and OpenCV. Thanks.

```
Step 1 : Feature Detection (Harris Corner Detector)
     2 : Local Invariant Descriptors (BRISK)
     3 : Feature Matching (BruteForce Matcher and Hamming distance)
     4 : Homography Estimation (RANSAC)
     5 : Perspective Warping (stitch)
```

Comment: Yes they are feasible. see sample from https://introlab.github.io/find-object/

Comment: most of thing in  opencv is supported in C++ and python. so should have no issue in converting

Comment: ok thks a lot much aprreciated